# Interpreting model

Tags: interpretation

If I trained a model (say logistic regression) on train, test and validation. During interpretation which dataset (test or validation) should I base on for interpretation? If test and validation shows some difference in performance (say 10% where test is higher than validation in terms of accuracy) does it indicate signs of overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that is probably overfitting.

There is a chance that your distribution of test set, is different to your training or validation sets - but this is quite rare.

Add some form of regularisation to to your model, which will flatten out the difference between your training and validation/testing sets.

Think of it like this: Every % increase in performance of your training set over your testing set, comes from your model learning to "memorise", rather than learning real patterns.

Comment: Thank your for the insight. When interpreting the model, should I used the test dataset or validation dataset? Say I want to present the logistic regression model built.

Comment: How are you defining each set? Which set is the one you haven’t used to tune any parameters?

Comment: train dataset is used to fit the model but the validation and test dataset has not been used to tune any parameters

Comment: Okay so there is no point in you having a validation and test set as they are serving the same purpose. 
I find it helpful to change the names to something more precise. Typically you have 3 datasets. Train, Validation, Holdout. You use Train to tune the model parameters directly. You use Validation to tune the hyper-parameters. Then once you have tuned all of your parameters for your full pipeline, freeze them. Take that frozen pipeline and run your holdout data through. This will give you an accurate measure of your models performance.

Comment: what is the difference between model parameters and hyper-parameters? is it the same where it is determined by GridSearchCV based on a range of values given?

Comment: There are all parameters - think of it as not using your holdout data to train any part of your pipeline. Probably separate questions that you can search / ask on here. Yes Cross-Validation is another approach, but I like to have a holdout set regardless. (so CV is just with train and validation datasets)